# Why tomcat increase always memory usage and never free it?

Tags: tomcat, memory-management, classloader

i have a Unix server with tomcat with one webapps in.

If i do free -h i view about 50% used:
With top command:
i view this process:

```
 21603 azureus+  20   0 7816556 1.104g  18200 S   0.0  45.1   0:36.41 


    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config
.file=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.loggi
ng.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.
protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.Secu
rityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-t
omcat-9.0.8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/tomcat-juli.j
ar -Dcatalina.base=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Dcatalina.home=/home/azureu
ser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/azureuser/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Use 45% of memory.

i want understand if is a problem of my code in myprojects or is a problem of TOMCAT.
My app is a springboot app with 2 controller:

here the code: https://pastebin.com/yq5F0XTG

I have 2 function:

- getAllTests called by requestController ->getTestList() that use URLClassLoader but I at end close it with:

  ```
  child.close();
  j.close() <--for JarFile that I load
  child=null;
  System.gc()
  ```
- runOne called by requestController -> runTest()
  also here it use ClassLoader but I at end close it with:

  ```
  loader=null;
  System.gc();
  ```

  When i call getTestList() and monitoring memory with top i view that TOMCAT instance increase memory usage 13.2 to 13.7 but at end it not decrease.
  Also with runTest()  memory increase but after end of method runOne() it dont decrease..

After many called to controller function i have problem with memory (60-70% usage).

It's a problem of tomcat configuration or is a problem of my code?

PS:I cant install nothing on unix server because i dont have privilege root and  VisualVM dont work from my windows local machine...

Please Help me.

Thanks all for any tips..

Answer (score 1):

Unless something changed in current JVMs that I'm not aware of: A JVM doesn't free up memory *to the Operating System*, if it doesn't use it: It will free up *its own* heap, but you've configured it at startup, allowing up to `-Xmx` memory. And that's what it takes (plus some).

If your application can get along with less memory: Change that configuration. However, once that memory is exceeded, your JVM will terminate with an OutOfMemory condition.

Choose that configuration wisely, and keep in mind: You've explicitly allowed your JVM to use up that amount of memory. Don't be confused if it takes you up on that allowance.

In production systems, I typically set `-Xmx` equal to `-Xms` to make sure that the JVM grabs all memory at startup, instead of failing to allocate more from the OS during a weekend night, causing a failure when I don't want to be alerted.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answe so for you is a problem of Tomcat setting not in my code?
If it is true then i communicate this to unix system administrator.
you are sure? i read in web that ClassLoader not free memory after i call it.. but I'm not sure

Comment: You should inspect the JVMs own heap to ensure that the memory _in the JVM_ is freed up again. But I consider it normal operation, that the JVM _never_ releases memory back to the operating system. What you describe does not give any hint for a memory leak within your application, but it also can't be ruled out.

Comment: ok So how set -Xmx and Xms memory limit in tomcat?
in this server i think that  these two options are not set and therefore fills the whole memory after long time..

Comment: Where to configure it? That depends on your implementation. The most standard location that I've seen is in tomcat's `bin/setenv.sh` (a file that you'll have to create yourself). It'll be typically some shellscript that's used to start tomcat. On Windows, if tomcat is installed as a service, it's in the service configuration (typically set when the service was installed). JVMs are unlikely to use up all memory - they rather have a default limit that you'll need to explicitly override in order for it to use huge amounts of memory.

Comment: ah ok thanks.. So for you classLoader not is a problem?

Comment: Impossible to say from here. Run that code 1000 times and check if you run out of memory. Your question is about the JVM handing back memory to the OS, and that won't happen. If you've introduced a memory leak into your application is impossible to say from the few lines of code you've given, and it's not the question you've asked before. Also, it's impossible to say in a static analysis of a bit of code. Measure, and you'll find out.

Comment: in pastebin you can view my class

Comment: Even that is just _a bit_ of code in the sense of _"impossible to say in a static analysis of a bit of code"_. But it will become apparent immediately if you _run that code 1000 times_ and _monitor the JVM heap_. Your question is about _handing memory back to the OS_ - and that part is answered. If you have more questions, just _ask another question_. But please don't ask to analyze your single class for memory leaks anywhere unless you've run the code and need help on how to prevent memory leaks that you can demonstrate happening.

Comment: ok now i run it 1000 times.. but i must set -Xmx value in setenv? if YES how? thanks